# How to define a table schedule?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a table `Schedules` where I can store the day(s) a `Person` work. Now I want to add the hours this `Person` works. Let's say `Person` works Monday from 9am to 11am, Tuesday from 9am to 6pm, and so on...

Also in every date range (from start_time to end_time ) how can I set the hours Person do not work like lunch time?

```
  create_table "schedules", :force => true do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
    t.integer  "person_id"
    t.boolean  "sun"
    t.boolean  "mon"
    t.boolean  "tue"
    t.boolean  "wed"
    t.boolean  "thu"
    t.boolean  "fri"
    t.boolean  "sat"
  end
```

Should I create a second table to store the hours of each day?

Comment: Hello @GSP, can you share your thoughts about this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think modeling a Person's work schedule will work better as a one-to-many:

```
Person
  has_many :shifts
end

Shift
  #fields person_id, day, start_time, end_time
  belongs_to :person
end
```

Then, to create the schedule you describe ('Monday from 9am to 11am, Tuesday from 9am to 6pm, and so on...'):

```
@person = Person.find(1)
@person.shifts.create!(:day => 'mon', :start_time => '9 am', :end_time => '11 am')
@person.shifts.create!(:day => 'tue', :start_time => '9 am', :end_time => '6 pm')
```

When you wanted to display this info, just iterate over the Person's Shifts:

```
@person.shifts.each do |s|
 puts "#{@person.name} works on #{s.day} from #{s.start_time} to #{s.end_time}."
end
```

You could choose to simply model 'lunch breaks' by giving the Person two shifts for that day . If, for instance, they worked from 9am to 7pm with an hour off starting at 1pm, give them on shift on that day from 9am to 1pm and one from 2pm to 7pm.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a ref table between Person and Days (for example) that would include the Time and the flag for whenever they work or not.